# Is any JavaScript code a valid TypeScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently I've started to learn `TypeScript`. From the documents I've studied for `TypeScript`, I saw some samples that pure `JavaScript` code could be compiled as `TypeScript` code.

My question is: **Is TypeScript language designed in a way that any JavaScript code will be a valid TypeScript code?**

i.e. is any `.js` file a valid `.ts` file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's assume *valid code* means : is *syntactically correct* with respect to the language specifications.

Then the answer is **YES**.

---

It is written down in the [TypeScript Specifications](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf?raw=true) (second paragraph) :

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. 
>   TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015)syntax.
>   **Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.**

(emphasis mine)

Now, most often *you don't want* basic JavaScript to be used "uncontrolled". After all, that was one of the reasons to create the TypeScript language in the first place !

Nevertheless, a valid JavaScript program *is* technically valid TypeScript. This is in the specifications probably by need of "backward compatibility", or, better formulated, by need of *[supersedence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supersedence)* to ECMAScript

---

To take the example of another answer, the Typescript code

```
var testVar = 4;
testVar = "asdf";
```

will be transpiled into exactly the same JavaScript code (with all default compiler options)

[Demonstration here on Typescriptlang.org playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20testVar%20%3D%204%3B%0D%0AtestVar%20%3D%20%22asdf%22%3B%0D%0Aalert(testVar)%3B)

**even though there is a TypeScript error, this doesn't prevent a valid javascript to be output from there**. It "compiles with error". (I wish this was called a warning instead of error, but anyway).

---

See also : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

> **Your JavaScript is TypeScript**
>
> TypeScript provides compile time type
>   safety for your JavaScript code. This is no surprise given its name.
>   The great thing is that the types are completely optional. Your
>   JavaScript code .js file can be renamed to a .ts file and TypeScript
>   will still give you back valid .js equivalent to the original
>   JavaScript file. TypeScript is intentionally and strictly a superset
>   of JavaScript with optional Type checking.

The simplest option that can deactivate this behavior (output js even though there are Type errors) is `--noEmitOnError`

Comment: As you can see in the playground, it's not valid typescript (see the red line under `testVar`

Comment: @FINDarkside This is an error in TypeScript, but nevertheless **it is still technically valid TypeScript, and the compiler outputs javascript from this, which happens to be exactly the same code**. I just tried it again now, with the exact same code than my link in the playground. I used `tsc myfile.ts`, without any tsconfig.json. I got the same error, but I also got a functional js file. As per the **specifications**. It is by design that it  works like that.

Comment: @FINDarkside Please also check https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html : ***Your JavaScript is TypeScript**
TypeScript provides compile time type safety for your JavaScript code. This is no surprise given its name. The great thing is that the types are completely optional. Your JavaScript code .js file can be renamed to a .ts file and TypeScript will still give you back valid .js equivalent to the original JavaScript file. TypeScript is intentionally and strictly a superset of JavaScript with optional Type checking.*

Comment: and just for the record, I tried this with tsc 3.1.3, but it should be the same for any version.

Comment: If your "compiles" means "compiles with errors", you should clarify your answer. It's pretty obvious that's not what you meant originally, because you said that `noImplicitAny` could make it not to compile, which by your definition of compile is false.

Comment: @FINDarkside fair point, indeed I added an edit to my question, mentionning the "`noEmitOnError`" wihch is more likely to be the correct option for my point. I'm going to remove the mention of the `noImplicitAny`.

Comment: Like many I'm struggling with the point of TS vs JS.  If "TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript." then that means a good developer can do everything Typescript does without the added compilation step, making TS a convenience and possibly even a crutch for developers not talented enough to write clean vanilla JavaScript - not unlike jQuery in that regard.  If all TS eventually compiles down to JS - then other than convenience, I don't understand the purpose.  Tools?  You still have to test the JS output, not just the TS before you put code into production.

Comment: @Carnix this point is more a technicallity. I'd _definitely_ do not recommend to deactivate the typescript "errors", even though it can spit valid javascript from the same javascript code. Take them into account and ripe the benefits! What you describe as crutches is  to me quite similar of the benefits given by other high-level languages over more low-level ones. C# ultmiately compiles to .NET runtime language, Java compiles to bytecode, etc... Also, the point of testing the result of compilation instead of the "original code" is valid for every compiled language, could you clarify the issue?

Comment: @Pac0  I'm not a freelancer.  My QA team alone has close to 30 people, to say nothing of the engineering, BA, and architecture teams.  When I think of including TS in front of the already existing JS dev for the front-end team, what I see is DevOps having to build yet more automation steps into the CI/CD, the QA team having to do a completely new round of testing on what amounts to interstitial code before they can test the *actual* functionality when that code is built into actual JS. I get the notion of types, but as long as your dev patterns are solid, I don't see the need for an extra step

Answer (score 14):

Not any valid JavaScript code is valid TypeScript see my example below.

```
var testVar = 4;
testVar = "asdf";
```

TypeScript gives the following error:
Cannot convert string to number.
To make that work in TypeScript add ":any" like below.

```
var testVar: any = 4;
testVar = "asdf"
```

This happens because TypeScript noticed testVar is declared and in the declaration it is assigned a number and therefore it decides it should stay a number.

Comment: another example `foo = 123` invalid in typescript as `foo` is never declared i.e. no `var` PS this code would fail in strict mode javascript as well.

Comment: for me the above Javascript code works in TypeScript file...Any suggestions?

Comment: This is true only if the Typescript compiler option `noImplicitAny` is `true`. With it being `false`, which is the default case, that is valid Typescript.

Comment: @Tuupertunut No, this is not valid TypeScript and I doubt it ever was. The error is that testVar has type `Number`, so this has nothing to do with `noImplicitAny`. I actually tried this with 3.1.6, 1.7.5 and even with the first available version on npm, 0.8.0 and none of them compiled the code above.

Comment: @FINDarkside
Did you check the compiled js file?
I just now tried, and though there is error, js file is generated.

Comment: @Dzenly Yes typescript will output a js file, but saying that it's valid typescript when it compiles with errors is misleading. By the same logic even `const a: string = 2;` is valid typescript. See the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per TypeScript Specifications : Archived doc [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.9.4/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification%20-%20ARCHIVED.pdf)

The statement
**"Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program."**

Implictely states below.

"Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program *with necessary/required changes in program such that it does not show any complication errors/warnings by TypeScript Complier"*