# "any" in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am beginner in typescript. I have a doubt in usage of "any" type.

Using "any" is basically opting out type checking if I am right. For example

1. `var num:any = 12`
2. `var num = 12`

we could probably use the second one itself, what's the need for 'any'?

Comment: Well your specifically saying it's `any`..  Otherwise it's implied it's `any`..   Would become more handy if say you was restructuring code, and you wanted to specifically mark this as handling any type.  It certainly has it's uses.

Comment: Javascript is valid typescript. the second one is javascript. You can use that but the explicitness of `any` is good, too. It lets you know that the developer made an informed decision to allow this variable to be dynamic

Comment: You would almost never use `any` for a number type.

Comment: While you didn't ask this directly, `any` is indeed (as you say) a bit of a "cop-out" in this case.  You'd likely want `var num: number = 12;` - to explicitly indicate you intend it to be used for numbers.  In that way, typescript would complain if you tried to use it in a non-numeric way....

Comment: If you omit the `any` in your code, then it becomes unclear to anyone reading the code (including you, possibly, in the future) - is that a mistake? Was it intended to have a type, but got missed? What should the type be? etc... `any` should be used to indicate that the type doesn't "fit" a known type (number, string, etc), or that it's possible it may change (which isn't a good pattern)

Comment: I disagree @cale_b. The declaration `var num = 12` is totally clear. Even traditionally strong typed languages like java allow this now because it's so clear, and `var num: number = 12` is just too much and doesn't help

Comment: @bambam - Interesting. then why use typescript at all?  The entire point is for it to notify you when you've used it in a way that disagrees with the declared type...

Comment: `let foo = 12; foo = 'bar';` results in an error because the string is not assignable to a number type. With and without typing. @cale_b

Comment: @bambam - well I'll be.... you are completely right.  Thanks for the convo - I learn something new here every day!

Comment: @cale_b yeah, me too... I actually found that by using java 10 which allows that kind of declarations now, and was wondering why a "loosely" typed language should be more strict here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the two are equivalent in use (because `any` is the default type when unspecified) by explicitly specifying the type as `any`, you explicitly declare the intent.

Intellisense, where available, will display the type as `any`, allowing easier understanding how your variable is meant to be used.

Comment: *"...because any is the default type when unspecified..."* That's incorrect when there's an initializer, as there is in the question. When there's an initializer, the type of the variable is [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#handbook-content) from the result type of the initializer expression. In the OP's example, the type is `number`; [proof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAdgrgthAvBAjAJgNwFgBQB6PCCAPQH4g).

Answer (score 10):

First of all - If we speak about Typescript, lets avoid the var key-word.

> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do not know when we are writing an application. These values may come from dynamic content, e.g. from the user or a 3rd party library. In these cases, we want to opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the any type:

Example to this:

```
let notSure: any = 4;
notSure = "maybe a string instead";
notSure = false; // okay, definitely a boolean
```

More:
[Types in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Answer (score 3):

> Using "any" is basically opting out type checking if I am right.

Right.

> For example
>
> ```typescript
> var num:any = 12
>
> var num = 12
> ```
>
> we could probably use the second one itself...

When you don't provide a type annotation but you do provide an initializer (`= 12`), TypeScript will [**infer**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#handbook-content) the type of the variable based on the result type of the initializer expression. In your example, for instance, it will infer `number`: [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAdgrgthAvBAjAJgNwFgBQB6PCCAPQH4g)

You'd use `any` if you wanted to be able to set `num` to something else, like a string, later, like this — but keep reading, I wouldn't do this ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdgrgtgLggQygTwgXggRgEwDcAsAFADGA9lAM4WgB0wFA5gBSxwCUxJHWEAIjAB3EMABuIAT0o06IRi3bxupIA)):

```typescript
let num: any = 12;
console.log(num);
num = "twelve";
console.log(num);
```

If you left the type annotation (`: any`) off, that would give you an error, because the type of `num` is inferred to be `number` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdgrgthAvBAjAJgNwFgBQBjAeygGcDQA6YAgcwApY4BKbHBpCAIjAHcRgA3EBxYB6EQD1ASETTJEACoBPAA4gIAcmJgATgEso1NRB3FoBSAENixHdSjmARqAhgCz5arUN7ILWvK00AGY0NEZcQhIyEEoaenhmXCA)):

```typescript
let num = 12;
console.log(num);
num = "twelve";
//^−−−− Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
console.log(num);
```

That said, since `any` opts out of typechecking, it's something you want to avoid whenever possible. In that example, if I had a really good reason for allowing the variable to be a number or a string, it would be better to give it the union type `string | number` (and probably change its name; [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwmgrgLYBGISEAvBAIwBMA3ALABQAxgPZrzugB0w7DAAooASibMolCACIwAdxDAAbiBkSOXHiH6CR4lkA)):

```typescript
let x: string | number = 12;
console.log(x);
x = "twelve";
console.log(x);
```

That way, if I try to assign a `boolean` (for instance) instead, I'll get an error.

> what's the need for 'any'?

The purpose of `any` is, as you said, to opt out of typechecking for that variable. Here's what [the `any` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) says:

> The `any` type is useful when you don’t want to write out a long type just to convince TypeScript that a particular line of code is okay.

But since the whole point of TypeScript is to provide static type checking, and `any` opts out of static type checking, in general `any` is best avoided whenever possible. It's not *always* possible (particularly when interfacing with untyped code outside the scope of your project), but when it's possible, it's generally best.

Answer (score 1):

Any: any type. Used when impossible to know the type.
When you declare type as any, you can reassign any type of value in that variable.

```
var num:any = 12;
num = boolean;
num = "abcd"
```

Answer (score -2):

`any` opts out type checking as you have said. The second description you have came up with (without `any`) will compile too. But it is not valid(*) when you use linting like [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/).

**(*)** By *not valid*, I meant the IDE you use will pop up an alert. But, to the bottom line; [any valid Javascript code is also valid for Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759532/is-any-javascript-code-a-valid-typescript-code) on the grounds of compiling.

Comment: _But it is not valid when you use linting_ That's just a matter of setting

Comment: Your IDE won't complain with the correct setting in tslint.json. If it does, get another one.. :-)