# How can i catch the width and height of a image link in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

i need to validate a link of a image if it has 1000px x 1000px and jpg.

Exemple:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/paris.jpg

I have this link, i need to catch the width and height of this image.

The jpg problem i believe that will be easy to do, I'll give a substring in the last few characters, but the question of image size I have no idea how i can find  in angular.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get width height of remote image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442712/get-width-height-of-remote-image-from-url)

Comment: i need in typescript

Comment: is a little different then javascript

Comment: Every javascript code is a valid Typescript (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759532/is-any-javascript-code-a-valid-typescript-code), as long as typescript is transpiled into javascript.

Comment: I try:   @ViewChild('imgprincipal') imgprincipal

My img:                       <img id="imgprincipal" class="rounded-circle miniaturaimg animated fadeIn" onerror="this.src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/190/190406.svg'"
                       src="{{produto.foto_prin_1}}" height="50"
                      width="50">

When i try to (console.log(this.imgprincipal.nativeElement.offsetWidth) i receive: "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Should't use id to bind via ViewChild, you should use #imgprincipal as explained here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/. You definitely should take a better look at how Angular and Typescript works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the javascript way :

```js
function getImageDimenstion(imgUrl){

   let img = new Image(); 

   img.src = imgUrl;
   img.onload = function (event) {
        let  loadedImage = event.currentTarget;
        let width = loadedImage.width;
        let height = loadedImage.height;
        console.log('height: '+height);
        console.log('width: '+width);
   } 
}

const url= "https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/paris.jpg";
getImageDimenstion(url);
```

working example for angular  :

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ub8jxm)

Comment: how can i catch this width/height in a typescript variable?

Comment: if i try this.width = width i receive: "[ts] Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: Late but typescript will agree with this: `let loadedImage = event.currentTarget as HTMLImageElement;`. Then, you can access all the [HTMLImageElement properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) like `loadedImage.width`

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd share my solution to this issue as I was hung up by not being able to access the image height and width outside of the callback function given in others' solutions. Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = "https://yourImageSource";
```

Now, if you want to use the image height/width, just use `img.naturalHeight` and `img.naturalWidth`.

NOTE: works in modern browsers in my Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

create a directive and use that as below:

```js
import { Directive,ElementRef,Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:"[imgDimension]",
  host:{
    '(click)':"calculate()"
  }
})

export class GetImageDmnsn{ 

  constructor(private img:ElementRef){

  }
  calculate(){
    console.log('height:' + this.img.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
    console.log('width:' + this.img.nativeElement.offsetWidth);   
  }
}
```

```html
<img imgDimension [src]="source">
```

Comment: When i try to put the link in img i receive  type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ElementRef<any>'.