# How to convert js to Ts of content explorer?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: content explorer error]    Converted the js file to ts file but still im facing error called content- 
    exlporer undefined .How to  use content explorer in angular2.

```
In js files javascript code 
    var hostURL = window.location.origin,
    baseURL = hostURL + window.location.pathname + "rest/";     
    var folderId, accessToken;
    var contentExplorer = new Box.ContentExplorer();
    var fileCollection = new Array();
```

In ts file typescript code

Declared all the variable of below parameters and added it into ngOninit.

```
  this.hostURL = window.location.origin;
  this.baseURL = this.hostURL + window.location.pathname + "rest/";
  const { ContentExplorer } = this.Box;
  this. contentExplorer = new ContentExplorer();
```

Comment: show the complete ts file and line no. of error ...

Comment: I would say this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759532/is-any-javascript-code-a-valid-typescript-code

Comment: in code everything  im converted but not able to convert this line                         var contentexplorer = new Box.contentexplorer() ;how to convert this javascript into typescript can u please suggest