# JSX element type 'Line' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to use chart.js with Typescript to build an application in React, however when attempting to render a Line chart I get the error described above on this line:

```
<Line data={data}/>.
```

Along with this I also get the message "Type 'ChartComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more."

Furthermore, when I use yarn start to run the application, the graph will render, but only for a split second before crashing with the error message.

I am fairly new to Typescript so I am confused as to what this error means. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Line from "react-chartjs-2"

class LineTest extends React.Component{

    render() {
        const data = {
          labels: [
            '10/04/2018', '10/05/2018', 
            '10/06/2018', '10/07/2018', 
            '10/08/2018', '10/09/2018', 
            '10/10/2018', '10/11/2018', 
            '10/12/2018', '10/13/2018', 
            '10/14/2018', '10/15/2018'
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Temperature',
              data: [22,19,27,23,22,24,17,25,23,24,20,19],
              fill: false,          
              borderColor: 'green'  
            }
          ]
        }

        return (
          <div className="App">
            <div>
              <Line data={data}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default LineTest
```

Comment: where is the error message?

Comment: `code`<Line data={data}/>

Comment: im not good at typescript, but had such problem because of ```;``` sign at the import. 
```import Line from "react-chartjs-2";```
Try to put and dont avoid semicolon

Comment: Line is named export in 'react-chartjs-2'. so use curly braces like {Line} instead of Line in import

Comment: Both of these do not resolve the error

Comment: try this incase of typescript
const Line = require('react-chartjs-2').Line;
instead of import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

Comment: Wow! That fixed it thank you very much! Would you be able to explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The `Line` component is exported by `react-chartjs-2` as a named export. You need to import it by its name:

```
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit laughing-cdn-3qp5q]

Comment: @jamesheaton Are you sure that you have rebuilt your app? Restart the watch task. You can see that your exact code works in the code sandbox that I updated my answer with. Also you have to install `chart.js` as a dependency as well.

Comment: What you have written is in Javascript, not Typescript

Comment: @jamesheaton 1. Your example is pure javascript as well and 2. this does not matter because typescript it a superset of javascript so valid javascript is also valid typescript. Typescript is just for static type safety. Look at the codesandbox. I copied your exact code and it works perfectly.

Comment: If I change the file extension to .js instead of .tsx the error goes away so it clearly is something to do with Typescript

Comment: @jamesheaton Then this may be a problem with incompatible typescript version or a configuration issue. But the code I posted works and is valid. What you see is a warning that shouldn't prevent your app from working properly.

Comment: @jamesheaton Typescript just adds static type checking to your application. It has no influence of the app at runtime. Valid Javascript is also valid Typescript. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759532/is-any-javascript-code-a-valid-typescript-code

Comment: Error was resolved by using 'require' as described above