# How to convert JavaScript snippet to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I convert the code from Javascript to typescript

```
const ORIENTATIONS = {
  single: () => 0,
  'right angled': (tag) => {
    return hashWithinRange(tag.text) * 90;
  },
  multiple: (tag) => {
    return hashWithinRange(tag.text) * 15 - 90;
  },
};
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
 const ORIENTATIONS: {
    single: () => number;
    'right angled': (tag: any) => number;
    multiple: (tag: any) => number;
}
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ single: () => number; 'right angled': (tag: any) => number; multiple: (tag: any) => number; }'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ single: () => number; 'right angled': (tag: any) => number; multiple: (tag: any) => number; }'.ts(7053)

Comment: What issues are you having while converting it?

Comment: actually, any JavaScript code is also technically valid TypeScript code (even though, by default, compiler could complain). What is your actual error?

Comment: It already is TypeScript.

Comment: related : [Is any JavaScript code a valid TypeScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20759532/479251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one class as

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  ORIENTATIONS = {
    single: () => 0,
    "right angled": tag => {
      return this.hashWithinRange(tag.text) * 90;
    },
    multiple: tag => {
      return this.hashWithinRange(tag.text) * 15 - 90;
    }
  };

  hashWithinRange(value) {
    return 45;
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qm5wdc