# Do we have labeled Statements in Typescript similar to what we have in JS?

Tags: angular, typescript, labeled-statements

I found this very interesting that we can break or continue a loop in Javascript. Do we have a similar concept in Typescript (Angular)?

```
let str = '';

loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    continue loop1;
  }
  str = str + i;
}

console.log(str);
// expected output: "0234"
```

Comment: Yes, try running your code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Most valid JS statements are valid TS statements too. There does exist some [edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20759532/6513921) though.

Comment: ok, it is working, is it native js that is used in typescript or typescript statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is working in typescript. However, it is a JS native statement that is compatible with typescript and is not part of typescript statements.