# Is it okay to put JS files in a tsconfig's includes/files property? Or how else can I make tsc check my JS files in a TS project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with a project that has a mix of Typescript and Javascript files, because we just adopted Typescript.  The project used to just have Javascript files, but by using a `jsconfig.json` file I was still able get Intellisense (eg. I could  `CTRL` + click on an import to go directly to the imported file).

However, since adopting Typescript (and getting the mix of files), VS Code has stopped offering Intellisense on Javascript files.  It works fine in Typescript, and I know for a fact that it's the file extension causing the problem, because if I rename `foo.js` to `foo.tsx`, the Intellisense starts working again.

I still have a `jsconfig.json` file, along with my `tsconfig.json` file, but clearly that's not enough to make VS Code restore Intellisense to JS files.  Can anyone explain how I can do that?

**EDIT:** Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["./app/*"],
      "pages/*": ["./pages/*"],
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }],
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: There's nothing else to reproduce the issue other the `tsconfig.json` file (I mean, I could show a basic JS file, but that won't tell you anything).  I've added that config file to the question.

Comment: Aha!  I was worried that would somehow confuse Typescript into thinking my JS files were TS files or something, but that seems to have worked :)  Would you like to put that comment in the form of an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: is the tsconfig.json file you have shown _minimal_ (see [mre])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to put patterns for JS files in a tsconfig's includes/files property. As for technicalities, I'm not sure if that causes the TypeScript compiler to think of those files as TypeScript files, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter too too much.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#moving-to-typescript-files and [Is any JavaScript code a valid TypeScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20759532/11107541) (answer is yes).

I think to get TypeScript to do checking in JS files, the JS file needs to either be included in the project via tsconfig, or imported by a file that is included in the project (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs).

Answer (score 0):

I think @starball's answer is correct. I had this same experience, and I just needed to pass both `js` and `jsx` values to the "includes" property in the `tsconfig.json`.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).